# Using $this when not in object context

Tags: ооп, php

```
Есть класс: testclass {
 мотоды: 
  function method1 {
  return true;
 }
  function method2 {
  if($this->method1 == false)
  {
    Echo "Ой";
  }
  else
  {
   return true;
  }

}
Расшираем класс:
test2class extends testclass
{
 методы:
 function method3 {
 if(parent::method2 == false)
 {
  echo 'Оёёй';
 }
}
Вызываем:
if(test2class::method3() == true) {
 echo 'Все ок';
}
/// Идёт ошибка на то, что строка - if($this->method1 == false)  " Использование $this, когда он не объект контекста," - Как устранить эту ошибку?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта строчка:

```
if(parent::method2 == false)
```

говорит о том, что используется статичный метод, следовательно ни о каком $this не может идти и речи.

Стоит переделать в методе method2:

```
if(static::method1() == false) //либо if(self::method1() == false), если необходимо использовать именно родительский метод
```

и в методе method3:

```
if(static::method2() == false)
```

и тогда заработает.

Почему static::method2(), если метод method2 описан в родительском классе? Потому что в данном примере в производном классе вы не перекрываете его.

Кроме того method2 не может быть объявлен как private, т.к. в противном случае вы не сможете вызывать его из производных классов.

Comment: Не до конца дочитал пример: test2class::method3().

Это же тоже статичный вызов класса, значит вы оперируете классом, а не объектом.

$this указывает на конкретный объект класса, поэтому его нельзя использовать в статичном вызове. Вместо этого используйте статичный переменные, например в области видимости protected.

Отредактировал пример в ответе

Comment: Благодарю, помогло.